# Tkinter bind does not call funtion

Tags: python, tkinter, pyhook

I am trying to change the text in a tkinter entry widget, to be the key combination entered by the user(example: ShiftL+ShiftR), the python program runs fine, but does not change entry, why and how can i fix it?
My GUI:

```
 # Program by Fares Al Ghazy started 20/5/2017
# Python script to assign key combinations to bash commands, should run in the background at startup
# Since this program is meant to release bash code, it is obviously non-system agnostic and only works linux systems that use BASH
# This is one file which only creates the GUI, another file is needed to use the info taken by this program

FileName  = 'BinderData.txt'
import tkinter as tk
from ComboDetect import ComboDetector

# Create a class to get pressed keys and print them
KeyManager = ComboDetector()


# Class that creates GUI and takes info to save in file

class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    # variable to store pressed keys
    KeyCombination = ""

    def KeysPressed(self, Entry, KeyCombination):
        KeyCombination = KeyManager.getpressedkeys()
        Entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        Entry.insert(0, KeyCombination)

    # constructor

    def __init__(self, FileName, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        # create GUI to take in key combinations and bash codes, then save them in file
        root = self  # create new window
        root.wm_title("Key binder")  # set title
        #  create labels and text boxes
        KeyComboLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Key combination = ")
        KeyComboEntry = tk.Entry(root)

        # Bind function to entry

        KeyComboEntry.bind('<FocusIn>',self.KeysPressed(KeyComboEntry, self.KeyCombination))

        KeyComboEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        ActionEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        # create save button
        SaveButton = tk.Button(root, text="save",
                               command=lambda: self.SaveFunction(KeyComboEntry, ActionEntry, FileName))
        SaveButton.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=tk.E)


app = MainFrame(FileName)
app.mainloop()
```

and ComboDetect:

```
   #this program was created by LadonAl (Alaa Youssef) in 25.May.17
    #it detects a combination of pressed key and stores them in a list and prints the list when at least
    # one of the keys is released

import time
import pyxhook

class ComboDetector(object):
    def getpressedkeys(self):
        return self.combo
```

Edit: I've changed the keyspressed function to test it

```
 def KeysPressed(self, Entry, KeyCombination):
        Entry.config(state="normal")
        Entry.insert(tk.END, "Test")
        print("test")
        KeyCombination = KeyManager.getpressedkeys()
        Entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        Entry.insert(tk.END, KeyCombination)
```

This is what I have noticed:
When the module is run, "test" is printed to console, nothing else happens.
When i try to click outside of the entry widget and click inside it again (exit focus and re-enter it), nothing happens

Comment: Try Entry.insert(tk.END, KeyCombination) instead of Entry.insert(0, KeyCombination)

Comment: @RainingComputers didn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure you are getting expected KeyCombination? Try printing it right after assignment.

Comment: @Lafexlos i think my problem is in KeyComboEntry.bind, since the function KeysPressed isn't called

Comment: This is way too much code. Please reduce it down to a [mcve]

Comment: @BryanOakley done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you attempt to bind to `KeyComboEntry`, you are calling the procedure `KeysPressed`, rather than passing `bind` the method for `KeyComboEntry`, you can fix this by using `KeyComboEntry.bind("<Key>", self.KeysPressed, KeyComboEntry, self.KeyCombination)`. Bind will then call `KeysPressed` with the arguments of `KeyComboEntry` and `self.KeyCombination`. The other alternative is to use a `lambda` function, as you have used for `SaveButton`, accounting for `bind` passing it an event.